# Does JasperReports/iReport work with Hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jasper-reports, ireport

I'd like to integrate existing application with JasperReports. However, when creating report with iReport the wizard is asking me for hibernate.hbm.xml. Since I'm using annotations I simply don't have one. Does iReport work with Hibernate annotations? If so, how can I configure iReport?

Comment: I know this is an old question but I would like to know as well

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if iReport can work with annotations, and even if that is the case, you still need a `hibernate.hbm.xml` (or a manual configuration, or spring).

What I suggest is to use the hibernate entities as POJOs in JasperReport - i.e. using `BeanCollectionDataSource`, and do all the operations for fetching the collection "outside" of JasperReport